# 1000 Photos to Virtual Canvas Gallery Wraps - Quick Method Needed

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, automation

I have to make 1000 virtual canvas gallery wraps. Like this: [image: Canvas Gallery Wrap]

How would you get this done?

I use Xara X for most of my graphics work. After Photoshop 6, I faded away from Adobe due to the software cost and constant upgrades, etc. I worked with Illustrator this summer, so I can download tools and get it done.

Ideally, I can drag and drop 1000 images and poof, 1000 modified images, tilted, shifted and wrapped. A bulk solution is best. :)

Comment: In Photoshop, you could record all of the necessary steps as an action and then run that as a 'batch' on a folder full of files. Does Xara X have a similar function to that...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple 3D shape in Xara then fill the face with the image... I feel I may be a bit late on this one though!

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I forgot about filling with an image. I'll test it out and update. I figured you need a some Stack Exchange love... I up voted. Don't let the down voters discourage ya.